# Can I dynamically generate a class that implements two or more interfaces?

Tags: java, reflection

I am generating class from a single interface by using proxy like so

```
public interface A {

    default String a() {
        return "a";
    }
}
```

```
A a = (A) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            A.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[] { A.class },
            new PassThrough());
```

and it works fine but I am wondering if i can generate the class that has access to every method out of multiple interfaces

```
public interface A {

    default String a() {
        return "a";
    }

    interface B {

        default String b() {
            return "b";
        }

    }

}
```

Something like

```
 AB = ...;
 AB.a();
 AB.b();
```

Comment: Mind if I ask what this accomplishes?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but according to the Javadoc, you can pass as many interfaces you like in, as the second argument to `newProxyInstance`.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can specify two or more interfaces if you want:

```
    Object o = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        A.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class<?>[] { A.class, A.B.class },
        new PassThrough());
```

The only "problem" is that there is no way to declare a variable that with the *intersection* type. In current versions of Java you can side step that using `var`:

```
    var ab = (A & A.B) o;
    ab.a();
    bb.b();
```

In previous versions of Java you would have to declare two different variables that both refer to the `ab` object you've created. For example:

```
    A a = (A) o;
    A.B b = (A.B) o;
    a.a();
    b.b();
```

Comment: You can declare variables with an intersection type, `var ab = (A & A.B) …`

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized you can use an intersection type in a cast